# Selector de hermano precedente CSS

Tags: css, css3, selectores-css

quiero ocultar a un hermano precedente en CSS, en función de la clase de un elemento interno que tenga el siguiente hermano. He probado con el selector has, pero no logro que funcione.

Sería algo como esto:

```
    .small:first-of-type:has(+.small>.vacio){
  display: none
}
```

Pero no me funciona, os dejo una captura de la estructura de la tabla y de los campos que quiero ocultar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Con este código lo he resuelto:

```
td.small:has(+td.small>.vacio) {
  
   
    display: none;
}
```